# How do I correctly operate tellg() and seekp() to accomplish this task?

Tags: c++, file-io

```
void edit_member()
{
    int ID;
    int slot;
    streampos pos;
    cout << "\n"
         << "Enter member ID#: ";
    cin.ignore();
    ID  = only_int();
    int mems = count_members();
    for (int a = 0; a < mems; a++)
    {
        if (ID == member[a].ID)
        {
            i_file.open("member_data.txt");
            for (int b = 0; b <= a; b++)
            {
                string void_data;
                getline(i_file, void_data, '#');
                pos = i_file.tellg();
                slot = a;
            }
            i_file.close();
            break;
        }
    }
    o_file.open("member_data.txt");
    cout << "\nEnter new name for ID# " << ID << ": ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, member[slot].name, '\n');
    o_file.seekp(pos) << member[slot].name;
    o_file.close();
    load();
}
```

I am trying to navigate to a specific point in a file and overwrite the name written there beside the corespondent ID#. I initially thought seekp() was similar to positioning the cursor in a text editor, so what i had done was attempt to position the cursor at the end of the name and "fill" with '\b' (backspace) for the length of the name, which is equivalent to

```
member[slot].name.length()
```

I removed the bit of code that advanced the cursor too far, and abandoned the backspace idea. Now I'm trying to put the 'cursor' at the beginning of the name and write over it. I also want to make sure that if the new name is shorter than the old one, the ends of the old one aren't still present in the file.

Currently what happens is the entire file is erased and the new name is present only at the beginning of the file. I'm a self taught and still pretty basic, but any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. writing to file is not like typing in notepad or any other file editor. when you put some string it won't push the rest, it will be overwrite the old text.
2. If the values doesn't have the same size you'll need to write all the rest of the file after the change. If you want to avoid it, you need keep some empty places (spaces) with the size and limit the input to the same width. and when you write the new value also give the same width.
3. you  need to open the out file for read/write, otherwise it will be truncated.

**EDIT:**

```
//when you open the file in write only mode, its content deleted. 
//to keep the old file content, you need to open for both read and write:
fstream outfile;
outfile.open ("test.txt",ios::in|ios::out);
```

Comment: I understand these concepts, however I'm still confused as to why the file is being written from the beginning despite positioning with seekp(). I was actually relying on the fact that the text, post new input, would be truncated. Thats what made me decide to abandon the backspace idiocy.

Comment: Ok, i think i have enough info to make a workable solution. Is it necessary to declare ifstream and ofstream, or is declaring fstream for both in and out going to be the same?

Comment: you can use the same `fstream` object. if you give `ios::in` to open, it will be the same as `ifstream` if you give `ios::out` it will be the same as `ofstream`.

Comment: You should also open the file in binary mode in order to use `seekg` etc. reliably